# How to write multiple random intercepts in lqmm?

Tags: r, random

I'm trying to define a linear mixed regression model using lqmm package with multiple random intercept terms. However, I do not find the good syntax to do it?
1. Is it possible to do it with the lqmm package?
2. If yes, do you know the good syntax to write it?
3. If no, do you know any other package (and associated syntax)?

Example of the syntax already used:

```
mod <- lqmm(fixed = Y ~ log10(X), random = ~ list(1,1), group = list(site.f,spp.f), 
            tau = 0.95, nK = 7, type = "normal", data = data_s)
```

It returns: `Error in model.frame.default(groupFormula, dataMix) :  type (list) incorrect pour la variable 'list(site.f, spp.f)`

```
mod <- lqmm(fixed = Y ~ log10(X), random = ~ 1, group = site.f + spp.f, 
            tau = 0.95, nK = 7, type = "normal", data = data_s)
```

It returns:

> Error in rep(weights, table(grp)) : invalid 'times' argument

Thanks a lot for your help
Vincent

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out Vincent? I am currently dealing with the same problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation I'm quite sure lqmm can only deal with a single group for the random intercept. However this shouldn't be a problem, by combining the two groups like so:

```
df$combined_group <- interaction(df$group1, df$group2)
df$combined_group <- as.factor(df$combined_group)
```

You may ask why - let's go back shortly to the math behind a mixed model, let's say you have a random intercept like so:

`y_ij` = `β_0` + `b_0i` + `β_1` * `x_1ij` + `β_2` * `x_2ij` + ... + `β_p` * `x_pij` + `ε_ij`

- `y_ij` is the response variable for the i-th observation within the j-th "group1" group.
- `β_0` is the fixed intercept.
- `b_0i` is the random intercept for the i-th "group1" group, drawn from a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance `σ^2_b0`.
- `β_1, β_2, ..., β_p` are the fixed effects coefficients for the p predictor variables `x_1ij, x_2ij, ..., x_pij`.
- `ε_ij` is the residual error, assumed to be normally distributed with mean 0 and variance `σ^2_e`.
- `x_1ij, x_2ij, ..., x_pij` are the predictor variables for the i-th observation within the j-th "group1" group.

compared to two random intercepts:

`y_ijk` = `β_0` + `b_0i` + `c_0j` + `β_1` * `x_1ijk` + `β_2` * `x_2ijk` + ... + `β_p` * `x_pijk` + `ε_ijk`

- `y_ijk` is the response variable for the k-th observation within the i-th "group1" group and the j-th "group2" group.
- `β_0` is the fixed intercept.
- `b_0i` is the random intercept for the i-th "group1" group, drawn from a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance `σ^2_b0`.
- `c_0j` is the random intercept for the j-th "group2" group, drawn from a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance `σ^2_c0`.
- `β_1`, `β_2`, ..., `β_p` are the fixed effects coefficients for the p predictor variables `x_1ijk`, `x_2ijk`, ..., `x_pijk`.
- `ε_ijk` is the residual error, assumed to be normally distributed with mean 0 and variance `σ^2_e`.
- `x_1ijk`, `x_2ijk`, ..., `x_pijk` are the predictor variables for the k-th observation within the i-th "group1" group and the j-th "group2" group.

Note that the subscripts "i", "j", and "k" represent the levels of the "group1", "group2", and observation indices, respectively. The specific notation and implementation may vary depending on the software or programming language you are using for your mixed effects modeling analysis.

This can be rewritten as follows:

`y_ij` = `β_0` + `b_0ij` + `β_1` * `x_1ij` + `β_2` * `x_2ij` + ... + `β_p` * `x_pij` + `ε_ij`,

where:

- `y_ij` is the response variable for the i-th observation within the combined "group1" and "group2" group.
- `β_0` is the fixed intercept.
- `b_0ij` is the random intercept for the unique combination of "group1" and "group2", drawn from a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance `σ^2_b0`.
- `β_1`, `β_2`, ..., `β_p` are the fixed effects coefficients for the p predictor variables `x_1ij`, `x_2ij`, ..., `x_pij`.
- `ε_ij` is the residual error, assumed to be normally distributed with mean 0 and variance `σ^2_e`.
- `x_1ij`, `x_2ij`, ..., `x_pij` are the predictor variables for the i-th observation within the combined "group1" and "group2" group.

By combining the "group1" and "group2" groups and creating unique combinations, you can treat the combination of "group1" and "group2" as a single grouping factor with its own random intercept. This allows you to model the random intercepts for both "group1" and "group2" as a single random effect, which can be estimated in a mixed effects model.